# Kernel headers after upgrading kernels from 3.5.7 to 3.9.0

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, kernel

I upgraded my kernel on Ubuntu 12.04 in order to gain access to the `include/uapi/`  headers.
The full kernel version that I upgraded to is **3.9.0-030900-generic**, following this [tutorial](http://www.howopensource.com/2012/07/how-to-install-linux-kernel-3-5-quantal-in-ubuntu-12-04-11-10-11-04-10-10-and-10-04/).

Unfortunately, the headers seem to have remained the same because the uapi directory doesn't exist. 
To diagnose the problem, I tried to download the source for my 3.9 kernel with:

```
sudo apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)
```

However the output is

```
Picking 'linux' as source package instead of 'linux-image-3.9.0-030900-generic'
```

And this results in the kernel source for **3.2** being downloaded instead of 3.9.

What action must I take to install the kernel/headers properly?

I looked through these two posts before posting for insights, to no avail:

- [update Linux Headers when Kernel is updated](https://askubuntu.com/questions/299415/update-linux-headers-when-kernel-is-updated)
- [Why are linux-headers not upgraded by apt-git dist-upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/224942/linux-headers-not-upgraded)

Comment: Mainline kernel are mostly for test, you can however install kernel 3.8 from ubuntu officual repositories.

Comment: Be aware that you can upgrade to the kernel 3.8 via official updates in Precide (Raring kernel) according to: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack , does this kernel contain the feature you want?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you download and install the headers appropriate to your architecture; either 32- or 64-bit, from here: http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.9-raring/

Comment: I currently have several header directories, both 3.5.0-linux-headers-3.5.0-23(-generic) and linux-headers-3.9.0-030900-generic. How do I ensure that the 3.9 is set as the default?  (Currently my attempts to compile code indicate that 3.5 is still being used)

Comment: Generally, any compile will attempt to use headers matching the currently running kernel: uname -r. If you are not running 3.9.0-xx, reboot and you may have to select it at the GRUB menu.

Comment: I am running 3.9.0-xx, according to uname -r. I also did a sudo update-grub and restarted just to make sure. (Same reuslts).

Comment: Do you have the exact matching headers installed? sudo dpkg -s linux-headers-$(uname -r) | head -n3  Where and how did you get the 3.9.0-xx kernel? The headers should be there, too.